# 質問の目的や意図を必ず明らかにすべき？

Tags: 討議

[手元の HTML ファイルをブラウザでホスト名 localhost で閲覧する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/36773/)

について、

> なぜ「普通にダブルクリックしてブラウザで開く」のがダメなのか、なぜ「localhostを使って」と言う指定が入っているの‌​かが全然わかりません。それらの改善がない‌​ままで再オープンの提案がなされると言うの‌​も全くわかりません

という指摘がコメントにてなされています。

質問には目的や意図を明示することが必須なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 9):

意図や目的を説明してもらわないと回答することが難しい、という質問は確かにありますが、全ての質問には意図や目的の明示が必要、とは思いません。

具体的にこの質問について言えば、目的はいろいろ考えられるものの、結局のところ実現方法は「ローカルでなんらかのHTTPサーバを起動する」しかないわけで、目的がなにかは重要な要素とは言えません。

ただし、環境が明示されていないと言う点はこの質問の問題点だとは思います。しかしこの点を指摘するコメントはありません。

--
質問の素直な解釈からはずれて他の可能性も考慮しなければならない、それをせずに質問の意図を想像しているのはおかしい、というのは結局回答者に意図を含めた完璧な状況説明を要求しているのと同じ事です。結果として解釈が誤りで質問の真意が別にあったということはままあることですが、だから全ての質問がそうだということにはなりません。

Comment: 「全ての質問には意図や目的の明示が必要、とは思いません」については、同意見です。が、「具体的にこの質問について」の『実現方法は「ローカルでなんらかのHTTPサーバを起動する」しかない』と言う断定の根拠が全くわかりません。ローカルでHTTPサーバを起動しても、それがlocalhostではアクセスできないと言う状況はありえるのに、なぜそのような断定をなさられるのでしょうか。元質問者に確認していただいたのでしょうか？「ローカルでなんらかのHTTPサーバを起動する」と言うのは「しかない」のではなく、可能な解決方法の選択肢の一つでしかありません。

Comment: 挙げられている質問文の中でHTTPサーバを起動している旨は何処にも記載されていないので、「Q.localhostでHTMLファイルを見るには？」「A.HTTPサーバを起動しましょう」は自然な回答だと思われますが……

Answer (score 5):

[OOPer さんの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2550/3054)の「別コメント」は私のものですので、意図を説明します。

---

> 他人には説明を求めるのに、自分は何の説明もしないと言うのはありなんでしょうか。

そういう行動をとっているつもりはありません。
私はクローズ理由が「なぜやりたいか分からないから」だとは思いもしなかったので、それに対して説明が必要だという発想が無かっただけです。
OOPer さんのコメントを頂いた後には返信いたしました。

そもそも、サイトの利用が初めての質問者に対して説明なしでクローズする事と、サイトの常連であるレビュアーの方々へ特に説明を加えずに編集や投票行動を行なう事を同列に並べるべきではないと思います。

また、私は「常に」クローズ理由を説明すべきとは思っていません。
ただ、OOPer さんがコメントで指摘された「なぜやりたいか分からない」といったクローズ理由は質問者さんには思いも寄らないだろう（私はそうでした）と感じますので、あらかじめ指摘するべき事だと思います。

> だいたい想像が付く事」と言うコメントもありますが、あくまでご自分にとっての想像でしかないわけで、その想像が正しいのかどうか、なぜ元質問者に確かめようとしないのでしょうか。

返信いたしました通り、私は「なぜ」かに関わらず回答可能だと考えていますので、確認する理由がなかったのです。

> 元質問者の意図も確認しないまま、一部の人の「想像」で質問内容を書き換えてしまうと言う今の状況には大きな危惧を感じています。

私の編集はタイトルに対するもので、

- 「index.htmlをlocalhost見る方法」
  を、
- 「手元の HTML ファイルをブラウザでホスト名 localhost で閲覧する方法」

にしたものです。
これは「想像」で行なったのではありません。
本文の内容を加え、タイポ的な不自然さを修正しただけです。

タイトルが日本語として不自然で読み取れる情報が少ないことが「うかつな質問」という印象を与え、クローズにいたった理由の一つと考えて行なったことです。

（それとも、「想像」で質問内容を書き換えているというのは別の投稿の話なのでしょうか？
それならば、別に Meta で投稿して問題提起していただくのがよいと思います）

> 複数の方が「質問内容がはっきりしない」と感じられている事に対して、自分一人が「だいたい想像が付く事」で何の説明も残さず再オープンの提案がなされる

上で説明いたしました通り、私はタイトルのうかつさが最大のクローズ理由だと思いましたので、編集で改善し再オープンに投票いたしました。
これは StackOverflow のシステム上、想定されている流れのはずです。

クローズというのは編集による改善を求める行為です。
その後、編集がなされるとレビューの対象になり、その編集が質問を十分に改善したかが、複数人で判断されます。
編集者一人で再オープンできてしまうようにはなっていないのですから、気軽にチャレンジしてよいと思います。

一々その度に議論を求められるのでは、誰も編集による改善をしなくなります。
片や、クローズ投票はボタン一つで出来るのですから、クローズされる一方になってしまいます。

> 自分一人が「だいたい想像が付く事」で何の説明も残さず

私が「だいたい想像が付く事」とコメントしたのは、OOPer さんのコメントの「なぜやりたいか分からない」という指摘に対してで、クローズした他のレビュアーに対してではありません。
OOPer さんのコメントがなされる前に説明するのは不可能です。

> どう考えても「自分に想像が付くものをわからないなんて言うのは、わからない方が悪い」と言う奢りのように感じられます。

私のコメントの主旨は、「なぜ」かわからなくとも回答可能だという事です。
つまり、「わからない方が悪い」でななく、「わからなくてもいい」です。

私が回答する際には、質問者さんの抱えている問題を全て理解して解決してあげようなどと考えていませんし、それが出来るとも思っていません。
人はみな自分の抱えている問題の専門家なのですから、他人が答えられる質問をしようと思えば、色々と削ぎ落したものになります。
StackOverflow はまさに、そういった周辺情報を、回答が可能な範囲で出来るだけ削ぎ落した質問が期待され、それを助ける場だと思っています。

Answer (score 0):

メタのネタですねと言って、メタで取り上げていただきましたので一言。

別コメントで『「こういった事は「改善待ち」にする際に指摘されるべき事だと思います。」については、大いに賛成』については、『「再オープン」を提案する際に指摘されるべき事』もあるはずだと言う意味を大いに含めたつもりです。

他人には説明を求めるのに、自分は何の説明もしないと言うのはありなんでしょうか。「だいたい想像が付く事」と言うコメントもありますが、あくまでご自分にとっての想像でしかないわけで、その想像が正しいのかどうか、なぜ元質問者に確かめようとしないのでしょうか。

元質問者の意図も確認しないまま、一部の人の「想像」で質問内容を書き換えてしまうと言う今の状況には大きな危惧を感じています。(以前「自分の質問とは意図が異なるが、それはそれで意味のある内容なので編集内容を受け入れる」なんて大人なコメントを残された質問者もありました…。)

複数の方が「質問内容がはっきりしない」と感じられている事に対して、自分一人が「だいたい想像が付く事」で何の説明も残さず再オープンの提案がなされると言うのは、どう考えても「自分に想像が付くものをわからないなんて言うのは、わからない方が悪い」と言う奢りのように感じられます。

Comment: 第三者による質問の意図を改変する編集は問題です。が、今回のmjyさんの編集がそうだとは思えません。他にもある、というのは具体例を別質問としてポストしてもらえませんか。

Comment: 説明を残さない再オープン票が「奢り」だというのはいくら何でもうがち過ぎです。単に「この質問はクローズしておく必要が無い」という意見表明に過ぎません。

Comment: 「他人には説明を求めるのに、自分は何の説明もしない」というのが何に対してのことなのかわからないのですが、説明を追記してもらえませんか